# Cancelling asyncio task run in executor

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm scraping some websites, paralelizing `requests` library using asyncio:

```py
def run():
  asyncio.run(scrape());

def check_link(link):
  #.... code code code ...
  response = requests.get(link)
  #.... code code code ...
  write_some_stats_into_db()

async def scrape():
  #.... code code code ...
  task = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(check_link(link));
  #.... code code code ...
  if done:
    for task in all_tasks:
      task.cancel();
```

I only need to find one 'correct' link, after that, I can stop the program. However, because the `check_link` is run in executor, it's threads are automatically daemonized, thus even after calling `taks.cancel()`, I have to wait for all of the other still running `check_link` to complete.

Do you have any ideas how to 'force-kill' the other running checks in the thread executor?

Comment: Why not switch to and asyncio-aware library like aiohttp or httpx? Then you wouldn’t need the executor.

Comment: I have to use a socks proxy over a SSH tunnel because of work policy, and requests makes that very easy.

Comment: Python threads cannot be cancelled, no matter which framework launches them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way, actually from my point of view, if you do not have to use `asyncio` for the task, use only threads without any async loop, since it makes your code more complicated.

```py
import asyncio
from random import randint
import time
from functools import partial

# imagine that this is links array
LINKS = list(range(1000))

# how many thread-worker you want to have simultaneously
WORKERS_NUM = 10

# stops the app
STOP_EVENT = asyncio.Event()
STOP_EVENT.clear()


def check_link(link: str) -> int:
    """checks link in another thread and returns result"""
    time.sleep(3)
    r = randint(1, 11)
    print(f"{link}____{r}\n")
    return r


async def check_link_wrapper(q: asyncio.Queue):
    """Async wrapper around sync function"""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    while not STOP_EVENT.is_set():
        link = await q.get()

        if not link:
            break

        value = await loop.run_in_executor(None, func=partial(check_link, link))

        if value == 10:
            STOP_EVENT.set()
            print("Hurray! We got TEN !")


async def feeder(q: asyncio.Queue):
    """Send tasks and "poison pill" to all workers"""
    # send tasks to workers
    for link in LINKS:
        await q.put(link)

    # ask workers to stop
    for _ in range(WORKERS_NUM):
        await q.put(None)


async def amain():
    """Main async function of the app"""
    # maxsize is one since we want the app
    # to stop as fast as possible if stop condition is met
    q = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=1)
    # we create separate task, since we do not want to await feeder
    # we are interested only in workers
    asyncio.create_task(feeder(q))
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[check_link_wrapper(q) for _ in range(WORKERS_NUM)],
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```